# Swift subclass versus protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am embedding a table view in a view controller and trying to access the parent view controller save button from the embedded table controller. if have the following protocol:

it works if my tableviewcontroller subclass (SettingsController) has a saveButton method and i use the following code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    guard let optionsTable = segue.destination as? SettingsController else { 
        fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
    }

    optionsTable.saveButton = self.saveButton

}
```

however, I am trying to use the following implementation, using a protocol:

```
protocol SettingsOptionsTable {

    var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem? {get set}

}
```

SettingsController is implementing the SettingsOptionsTable protocol. Yet the code below:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

     guard let optionsTable = segue.destination as? SettingsOptionsTable else {
         fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
     }

     optionsTable.saveButton = self.saveButton

 }
```

gives me a compile error:"Cannot assign to property: 'optionsTable' is a 'let' constant"

I don't understand why. The optionsTable object is constant, implements the protocol and I assign a property.
The code then works if I change "guard let" to "guard var".
Anyone could explain this to me ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the protocol is related to a class with *reference* semantics add the `class` attribute

```
protocol SettingsOptionsTable : class {
```

Otherwise the protocol is treated as an object with *value* semantics and that causes the error.

From the documentation:

> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference semantics rather than value semantics.